# How to send data using resultreceiver, while the class is extending from thread

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a service class by which i send some data to my activity

```
public class baseApi extends Service {

@Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  //get the receiver object
        resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
}


  private BroadcastReceiver datachanged_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //HERE I send some data like this
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
                bundle.putString("data", "My data goes here");
                resultReceiver.send(100, bundle);
}};
}
```

In the same class I have a class extending "thread", and this class also intends to send some data to UI using the resultReceiver , it doesn't give any exception, but no data gets received at the UI end either, while the resultReceiver sending data via the broadcast receiver works well.

```
public class baseApi extends Service {

@Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  //get the receiver object
        resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
}


  private BroadcastReceiver datachanged_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //HERE I send some data like this
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
                bundle.putString("data", "My data goes here");
                resultReceiver.send(100, bundle);
}};

class actionThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try{
                         //send this data to the service        
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle.putString("data","More data goes here" );
             resultReceiver.send(200, bundle);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't give any exception". How can you know that since you catch all the exceptions and do nothing with them?

Comment: I am catching all exceptions, but not in the code above, its just a representation of my use case

Comment: in your `actionThread` class in the code above, you use `try .... catch(Exception ex) { **nothing here**  };`

Comment: As i said its just a representation of my case, I do catch all the exceptions in the log, I am debugging it right now, I just want to know the logical reason as to why won't my data go to the activity using the resultreceiver, when its called from within a thread. does LOOPER has something to do with it, I am new to Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android, you could use `Handler` to communicate with UI thread. Just use `Hanlder.Post` or `HandlerThread` instead.